# Taking specific date data from a variable initially made with new Date()

Tags: javascript

When inserting my blog post into MongoDB, I create a new date using new Date();

It becomes that format: `Thu Mar 06 2014 18:51:17 GMT-0500 (EST)`

How can I create a variable that becomes 18:51, March 06, 2014 (EST) from the above data?

I thought about using "split" to create an array with each of the elements, and then create a new date variable with just the elements I need. Maybe best way to go?

Comment: Not clear what you're asking.  You want to create a JavaScript Date from a date string?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: Yes, the date is stored like the above into MongoDB. I want to modify it before displaying it on my blog. I'm trying to think of ways to create an array after stripping all the white spaces, then taking each array element that I need, but might not be the optimal thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript objects have a `toString` function, that is responsible for converting them to strings. Not sure if it will help, but you can override it.

```
var testDate = new Date();
testDate.toString = function() {
  return this.getHours() + ':' + this.getMinutes();
}
```